# Including only one row in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

What I'm trying to do is take these records that looks like this:

```
ID  NAME    STARTDATE   ENDDATE   EnrollmentMonth
1   PETER   20200705    20200729    20200701    
1   TONY    20200730    99991231    20200701
```

and change it to look like this:

```
ID  NAME    STARTDATE   ENDDATE   EnrollmentMonth
1   PETER   20190101    20200729    20200701
```

Including the name that has enrollmented in 15th of the month, Peter enrolled in the 15th of July while Tony did not.

The idea is to pick only one name in July.

I am having difficult time making this work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In the expected outcome - 20190101 is there. From where to fetch it? or is there any logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want to filter rows where `startdate` is earlier than the 15th of the enrollment month:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.startdate <= trunc(enrollmentmonth, 'month') + interval '15' month
```

If `enrollmentmonth` is always the first of a month, we can dispense `trunc()`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.startdate <= enrollmentmonth + interval '15' month
```